# How to add policy to Product in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I need help with adding policy to PRODUCT in Azure APIM.
Could you please let me know how we can achieve using PowerShell/Azure Cli/ Azure DevOps?

Comment: For DevOps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/devops-api-development-templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to [Set a product-scope policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/set-azapimanagementpolicy?view=azps-6.6.0#example-2--set-a-product-scope-policy)

```
PS C:\>$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "Api-Default-WestUS" -ServiceName "contoso"
PS C:\>Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ProductId "0123456789" -Policy $PolicyString
```